# Save as CSV saves file with formulas as #NAME?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module function in this report that concatenates certain cells:

```
Function AnalysisResults(Specs As Range, Results As Range)
    AnalysisResults = Join(Specs) & ";" & Replace(Join(Results), ",", ".")
End Function

Private Function Join(Range As Range, Optional ByRef Delimeter As String = " ")
    Dim Str As String
    For Each cell In Range
        If Str <> "" Then Str = Str & Delimeter
        Str = Str & cell.Value
    Next

    Join = Str
End Function
```

Then i have a command button that save my file as CSV. It works, but the where the function cells are the value saved is **#NAME**?.
If I Save As manually as CSV comma delimited, it saves correctly and the formula values appears.

Here is the code of the `CommandButton`:

```
   Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Specifica numele WBT-ului de descarcare:", "Save WBT with the following name", 1)
Range("L2").Value = myValue
Dim CopyToCSV()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String
Sheets("Manual Discharge WBT").EnableCalculation = True
MyPath = "\\FILES\Transfer\~~TTS Import (do not delete)~~\Import Files\"
MyFileName = Range("L2") & " Discharge " & Format(CStr(Now), " dd_mm_yyyy_hh_mm")
If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
Sheets("Manual Discharge WBT").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:= _
        MyPath & MyFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSVWindows, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
     MsgBox "Fisierul tau s-a salvat ca: " & MyFileName
End With
```

Comment: Looking forward to your comments

Comment: What for value is in `Range("L2")` ?

Comment: It's whatever i enter in the InputBox (myValue). See first code line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is, you will have to save your `AnalysisResults` and `Join` functions as an add-in file `.xlam` and add to excel at `Developer->Add-ins`. Doing it this way the above code worked for me when saving to CSV without `#NAME?`

What was happening here was that when excel is trying to save the file to CSV, it doesn't know what the `AnalysisResults` function is.

Comment: I understand. I thought there was a way to do it without the .xlam . It was originally in an .xlam but i copied the data from it's module in another module directly in the report, and then this happened. So, thank you anyway...at least now i know :)